# Android Studio Help - Change Text and remember it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-widget, android-button

```
package org.pltw.examples.collegeapp2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Jarod Weaver on 2/24/2017.
 */

/**
 * PLTW, 2016.
 */

public class FamilyMemberFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private TextView firstName, lastName;
    private EditText mFirstName, mLastName;
    private FamilyMember fam;
    private Button mSubmitButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_family_member, container, false);
        FamilyMember fam = new FamilyMember();
        fam.setFirstName("Ada");
        fam.setLastName("Lovelace");
        mSubmitButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.familyMemberSubmitButton);
        mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                     // area where help is needed
                     // trying to take the text typed from text inputted and setting the TextView to that and remember it even after switching tabs
            }
        });
        firstName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fn);
        firstName.setText(fam.getFirstName());
        lastName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ln);
        lastName.setText(fam.getLastName());
        mFirstName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mfn);
        mLastName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mln);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

If you guys need any more pieces of the code to help it out, let me know. I am trying to take the text you input from TextEdit and setting TextView to it and having it to the point that it will be remembered even after leaving the app and even switching the navigation. In other words since I am learning through PLTW, here is what they are asking for:

Add a Button named mSubmitButton to the FamilyMemberFragment so that when the user presses this new button, it updates the first and last names by replacing them with the contents of the text field. Previously you have used the onClick XML property to do this. When working with Fragments, it is much more convenient to use anonymous inner classes. The following steps will help you setup a listener for your button’s click using an anonymous inner class.

a. Call the setOnClickListener method of mSubmitButton.

b. As a parameter, type new O and select the first autocomplete option that appears: 
[pic from PLTW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVEKy.png)

This automatically generates the OnClickListener that you need to add functionality to your Button’s click.

c. Fill in the onClick method that appears with the code that you want to have execute when the Button is clicked.

17. Test out your button to make sure that the Model and Presenter layer objects are being changed as you’d expect.
18. Once they are, test what happens if you change the first or last name, and then navigate away from the FamilyMemberFragment and then back to it.

Any ideas and how to do it? Trying to stick with how PLTW wants it without looking at the key.

Comment: use shared preferences to store values.

Comment: Sharedpreferences not working too well.

Answer (score 0):

use Shared prefrences or sql lite if u want to track your data through out the application even when applcation is closed